# Add a property to the type of an Array typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Working on a chat app, I encountered a problem trying to add a property to the array of object.

```
    // original array 
    const authors: User[]  = []
    //But I wanted to add something like this
    const authors: User[] & { otherProperty: string }[]  = []
```

I thing I could extend the array outside and then make it an array, but it is posible to do it with an intersection? I'm honestly curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the property to `User` right?

```
const authors: (User & { otherProperty: string })[] = [];
```

Comment: You can add parenthesis?, well, that was easy. thanks!